# Post Flag History page for nomination doesn't show a title

Tags: bug, flags, moderator-tools, election, nominations

One of the nominations in [our election](https://ell.stackexchange.com/election) received a comment flag. When I look at the post flag history ([link for staff to reproduce](https://ell.stackexchange.com/admin/posts/320081/show-flags)), the description of the post is missing:

[image]

Normally, that's filled with the title of the question (but if it's the flag history of an answer, it links to the answer). It should either say something like "Nomination by ..." or the word "for" should be dropped - there are other ways to get to that page, like the back button of your browser.

Comment: Yep, I think basically everywhere there are flags/comments/etc. on election nominations, the system doesn't know how to display the "post title" and so it just leaves it blank.